# Js to generate a sequence of array

Tags: javascript

I am give start and the end and the size, I am required to generate array as in illustration

when

```
start = 1

end = 100

size = 10
```

the expected result is

```
[
  [10,20],[20,30],[30,40],[40,50],[50,60],[60,70],[70,80],[80,90],[90,100]
]
```

UPDATE

second example

When

```
start = 1

    end = 100
    
    size = 10
```

expected result

```
[[5,10],[10,15],[15,20],[20,25],....[90-95],[95,100]]
```

I have tried with,

```js
var start = 1;
end = 100
size = 10;
result = []
for (var i = start; i <= end; i+=size) {
    result.push([i, i + size-1])
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: What are the actual rules to generate the array? In your example, it isn't very clear how each of the starting variables (`start`, `end`, `size`) relates to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply changing `[i, i + size-1]` to `[i - 1, i + size-1]` seemed to work just fine. The first element in the array doesn't match your example, but it can easily be removed. Full code below.

```js
var start = 1;
end = 100
size = 10;
result = []
for (var i = start; i <= end; i += size) {
  if (i <= start * 10) { 
    end += 10;
    continue;
  }
  result.push([i - start, i + 9 - (start - 1)])
  if (i > 200) break
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: I have added a way to remove it.

Comment: If you do what I said at the end of my answer, it gives the expected result.

Comment: @CodeGuy I revised it one last time, this should fit your needs. It gives the expected result every time, even when `start` is changed.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    start = 1;
    end = 200
    size = 5;
    result = []
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i += size) {
        if (i == start) continue;
        result.push([i - 1, i + size - 1])
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const start = 1;
    const size = 10;
    const end = 100;
    const result = [];
    for(let i = start; i < end; i += size) {
    // Checking if it is the first iteration
    if(i == start) continue;
    // Else adding size in the next iteration and adding in 
    // resulting array
     result.push([i-1, i + size - 1])
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Hope it solves your problem !!! :) cheers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```js
var end = 100
var size = 10;
var result = []
for (var i = size; i < end; i+=size) {
    result.push([i, i + size])
}
console.log(result)
```

check this,
this code gives the same output you wanted.
updated one with the start

```js
var start = 1
var end = 100
var size = 10;
var result = []
for (var i = start; i < size; i++) {
    result.push([i * size, (i + 1) * size])
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is wrong, we need start value, you are not at all specifying start

Comment: what is the use of start value, when there is no use?

Comment: @CodeGuy check this then,,   ````var start = 1;
var end = 100;
var size = 10;
var result = [];
for (var i = start; i < size; i++) {
    result.push([i * size, (i + 1) * size])
};
console.log(result);  ```

Comment: Pls revise your answer

Comment: When I make start as 11, your code returns empty array